# How does this Is64BitOS pointer-arithmetic-based function work?

Tags: c++, windows

Reversed this function. It works. But stepping through I can't figure out how. Why does this work?

```
bool   _Is64BitOS(void) {
    unsigned int version = *(unsigned int*)0x7FFE026C;
    unsigned int address = version == 10 ? 0x7FFE0308 : 0x7FFE0300;
    ILog("Running %u-bit system\n", *(void**)address ? 32 : 64);

    return (*(void**)address ? false : true);
};
```

Why do we find `0x0A` at `0x7FFE026C` on a 64 bit Windows install? Its beyond the address space of all modules on a 32bit binary, looking at memory it looks like it's just before the heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is accessing the [KUSER_SHARED_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-kuser_shared_data) structure using its conventional address of `0x7FFE0000`. `0x7FFE026C` corresponds to the `NtMajorVersion` field. Then it tries to access `SystemCall` field, which is at different offsets depending on if it is pre or post Windows 10, hence the check:

> `SystemCall`
>
> On AMD64, this value is initialized to a nonzero value if the system operates with an altered view of the system service call mechanism.

Also see: [Why doesn’t Windows use the 64-bit virtual address space below 0x00000000`7ffe0000?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221216-00/?p=107598)

Comment: What a hideous hack.  There must be a cleaner way.

Comment: My god, this is so gross and wonderful at the same time. I love little ways around the Windows API like this but I would never actually put this in real code.

Comment: @PaulSanders The cleaner way is to use [IsWow64Process2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2) to check if it is a WOW64 process if `_WIN64` is not defined.

Comment: @PaulSanders `IsWow64Process` for backwards compatability or on Windows 10 and later `IsWow64Process2`

Comment: @Pulpo This hack saves a couple syscalls, I guess that's why people use it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Hmmm, how pointless

Comment: @PaulSanders What is pointless?

Comment: Saving two syscalls.  I mean, in any meaningful way, what do you stand to gain?